# How to convert text to a number in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-forms

I've built a form that dumps data to a Google spreadsheet and that data, studio reads it... and turns that into a dashboard.. only problem is the text doesn't convert very well for building a dash board. I need Numbers!

That being said I would like to turn my `yes` or `no` responses, which could be in any cell and be either or into a `0` or a `1`.

Example:
form response date 4-22-21, cell `A1` has a `YES` or a `NO` response.
I would like this response to be shown as a "1" for yes and "0" if its no in another cell  like `A7`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new sheet/tab and try the following formula. *(You should NEVER touch the `Form responses` tab)*

```
=INDEX(SWITCH('Form responses'!B2:B,"YES",1,"no",0,""))
```

[image]

*(please -as always- adjust formula according to your ranges and locale)*

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`SWITCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/)